# Upgrade SQL 2008 R2 Standard to Enterprise Edition in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sql-server, upgrade, edition

We are using SQL 2008 R2 Standard edition with SharePoint 2010.  If we decide later on to upgrade to the SQL 2008 Enterprise edition, what is the process and the impact on the SharePoint environment?

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do to upgrade is enter am Enterprise license key.  No impact on SharePoint.  Should be seamless.